# How to keep constant load of 400 RPS using Concurrency Thread Group and Throughput Shaping Timer combination

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I Want to make a test case to send 50,000 Requests with 400 RPS using Jmeter.
I have been suggested to use combination of Concurrency thread group and Throughput Shaping Timer for this use case and I have tried following from the following link: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin.

- Here the problem is I only get ~28K responses recorded in csv instead of 50K.
- I need to make 400 RPS irrespective of the request sent the previous second
- I also need to have time difference of ~1sec for each 400 rows so that I can confirm 400 requests are sent every second.

Any Other suggestions to achieving the same result are also okay.

*I have used 400 as start and end rps and duration of 125 second considering 400 * 125 = 50,000*

*I have attached the image of my concurrency thread group too*[image: concurrency thread group]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to send 400 RPS with 400 threads your application **must respond in 1 second or less** because JMeter waits for the response from previous sampler before starting the next one. If your application response time will be 2 seconds - you will get 200 RPS, 4 seconds - 100 RPS, etc.

If your application response time is higher - you need to increase the number of threads proportionally, your 40 spare threads might be not sufficient.

Also JMeter needs to be able to send requests fast enough so make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/) if needed

If your application under test cannot handle 400 RPS - there is nothing you can do from JMeter side, you can only identify the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) and either report it or fix it yourself prior to re-running the test

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Also I took up on your suggestion to do Distributed testing and it worked good. But I have 2 issues. 
1. I get this error `Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException/Non HTTP response message: Socket closed`. So is this error from my side or jmeter's?
2. I got 1,95,358 responses instead of 2,00,000. Its minor only, but would like to know why.